# rewriting url in php mvc and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I use my own php mvc
My htaccess:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sekilwak/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How to rewrite 
"domain.com/user/index/username" to "domain.com/username"

Answer (score 2):

First method is through `.htaccess` file you can write rewrite rules -

Write the following code in `.htacces` file in your project root directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/username/(.*)$ /user/index/username/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

**You can Also Use Apache Rewrite Module -**

If you are using CodeIgniter you can use Steps and code as below -

- In your Project folder go application folder
- Then Open Config folder
- Then open `routes.php` go to end of file and add code below

  `$route['username']="user/index/username";`

It will automatically add `domain.com` to both side url's

Comment: @rule check the answer and let me know